# ValueError: Input 0 of layer "conv2d_21" is incompatible with the layer: expected min_ndim=4, found ndim=2. Full shape received: (None, 19222)

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I'm developing a keras model for binary classification using cell genetic information from an h5ad file.
My training data is a 35000 x 19222 float matrix.

Labels:

```
labels = adata.obs.tier_0_hallmark_corrected
labels = labels.map({'Tumor': 1, 'Normal':0})
labelsSample = labels.iloc[:35000] #shape: (35000,)
```

The training samples:

```
expression = adata.to_df()#this is taken from a file that contains genetic information
expressionSample = expression.iloc[:35000] #Shape: (35000, 19222)
```

Keras model:

```
input_dim = 19222

model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv2D(64, 3, activation='selu', input_shape = (input_dim,)))
model.add(Conv2D(64, 3, activation='selu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(BatchNormalization())
model.add(Conv2D(128, 3, activation='selu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(BatchNormalization())
model.add(Conv2D(128, 3, activation='selu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(BatchNormalization())
model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))
model.summary()
```

When I execute the model I get: `ValueError: Input 0 of layer "conv2d_21" is incompatible with the layer: expected min_ndim=4, found ndim=2. Full shape received: (None, 19222)`. I assume I have to reshape the input data into the model but I don't really know what shape should it have. I'm pretty new to DL so help is much appreciated ;)

Comment: `expressionSample` is the x train data for your fit right?

Comment: You should investigate a bit the content of your train data. [Conv2D](https://keras.io/api/layers/convolution_layers/convolution2d/) expects an `input_shape` of 4. You are inserting a shape of 2 (1922 and the batch size that is taken automatically). For example, if train data are images 28x28 RGB (three channels) the input_shape would be (28, 28, 3) -> 4 dimensions (including batch size). You have to understand better the content of your data and possibly reshape it. Or maybe this is not the right architecture for you

Comment: Okay, thanks for you reply!
I was wrong when using Conv2D, I should have used Conv1D

Comment: I added the solution as answer so that can be better found by others

Answer (score 0):

You have a problem with the shape of the input.
You should investigate a bit the content of your train data. Conv2D expects an `input_shape` of 4. You are inserting a shape of 2 (1922 and the batch size that is taken automatically).
For example, if train data are images `28x28` RGB (three channels) the `input_shape` would be `(28, 28, 3)`. So you would have 4 dimensions (including batch size).

You have to understand better the content of your data and possibly reshape it. Or maybe this is not the right architecture for you.

As the OP was saying in the comments the final solution was to change Conv2D to Conv1D.